# Disallow an action with robots.txt file in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.Net MVC applcation i have a controller/action url which i want to add in Robots.txt Disallow section so that my view will not be crawle and so not indexed by search engines.

But i have renamed controller/action using routes like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "693a7878-4b1d-4934-bad2-cec60e4ffbd1ec801ac0",
                "693a7878-4b1d-4934-bad2-cec60e4ffbd1ec801ac0",
               new { controller = "Index", action = "Report" }
           );
```

so  my url is like this

```
http://localhost:51227/693a7878-4b1d-4934-bad2-cec60e4ffbd1ec801ac0
```

i want to know in Robots.txt Disallow what url I should include to get ignored by search engines.

```
 User-agent: *
 Disallow: /Index/Report

          OR

 Disallow: /Index/693a7878-4b1d-4934-bad2-cec60e4ffbd1ec801ac0
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should block `/693a7878-4b1d-4934-bad2-cec60e4ffbd1ec801ac0` if you only want that specific URL to be ignored by crawlers.

However, they will still find your `/Index/Report` URL so you might want to block that too?

Answer (score 0):

A search engine doesn't (necessarily) know you use ASP.NET MVC, nor how your routing is set up. It just sees the final URLs. See [The Web Robots Pages](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html):

> you need a separate "Disallow" line for every URL prefix you want to exclude

So the 'forbidden' URL:

```
http://localhost:51227/693a7878-4b1d-4934-bad2-cec60e4ffbd1ec801ac0
```

Becomes:

```
Disallow: /693a7878-4b1d-4934-bad2-cec60e4ffbd1ec801ac0
```

Comment: @Anton in another answer mentioned they can still find /Index/Report, so need to include both in Disallow?

Comment: Yes, any URL that leads to a resource you want to disallow access to.